# What is the meaning of ColorSpace -> Automatic?

Tags: image-processing, color, display

The colour space of an image can be retrieved using `Options[im]` or `ImageColorSpace[im]`.  A possible value is `Automatic`.  This is what we get when using `ColorCombine[channels]` without specifying an explicit colour space.

What is the exact meaning of `Automatic`?

It seems to display like RGB when there are three channels. But it works with any number of channels.  How is the colour of a pixel computed when we have a different number of channels than three?

---

Example:

```
im = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}]
```

[image]

```
{r, g, b} = ColorSeparate[im];

ColorCombine[{r, r, g, b}]
```

[image]

Comment: According to the `ImageColorSpace` Doc page, `ColorSpace -> Automatic` means that "no color space specified". So it seems to be a display issue.

Comment: I think it deserve to ask support..

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Not just display, but also determining the output of `ColorConvert[manyChannelImage, "RGB"]`.  It seems to blend adjacent channels according to some rule that's not quite clear to me.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov `{a,b,c,d}` converts as `{a,(b+c)/2,d}` and `{a,b,c,d,e}` as `{a,(b+c)/2,(d+e)/2}`.  I haven't tried more than 5 channels yet.

Comment: I would expect `ColorConvert` to produce an error on such images. Current behavior is simply misleading.

Comment: `ColorCombine` simply gives you a four channel image with no defined colorspace.  (You can see by extracting `PixelValue`'s).  The real question is what does the front end do to display such image.

Comment: The formula turns out to be simple: for a number of channels a multiple of 3, partition into threes and take the average of each group.  For non multiples of three, take one less value on the first group or first and last as needed. eg 13 channels gives `{(a+b+c+d)/4,(e+f+g+h+i)/5, (j+k+l+m)/4)}`

Comment: Reported as CASE:3963067.

Comment: Asked at WC: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1207685

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It seems that every image *must* have a colour space. This is clear from the LibraryLink interface to images. I guess they needed some "colour space" that could be used for arbitrary images, with any number of channels. Once they had that, there was the question of how it is displayed (or converted to another colour space), so the simple blending described by george2079 was implemented. I would not trust this method to be stable between versions though.  I guess "Automatic" means "I don't care, I just want to have many channels".

Comment: Does LibraryLink allows `ColorSpace -> Automatic`? Or only explicit colorspace?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It does allow it, it's just one more value among the other colour space values.  I wasn't sure what it was when I first saw it, that's why I asked this question originally.

Comment: I still think that consistent implementation would be to return `$Failed` and error message when trying to `ColorConvert` an image with `ColorSpace -> Automatic`. Current behavior just deceives the user. How such an image is displayed is another thing (much lesser important from my point of view).

Comment: @Alexey Yes, I agree that at least a warning would be preferable.  I am not sure I would go as far as make it fail, especially when the image had 1 or 3 channels. There are also operations that imply colour space conversion, such as exporting to certain formats.